# Why Late Answer queue flooded?

Tags: discussion

Today i noticed, the Late Answer queue was flooded with answers(almost 160+ many of them are 1 year or so old).

I tried clearing up something and it kicked me out after 20 saying come back after 23 hours.

Why there is a sudden hike in Late Answer queue?

Comment: Was about to post the same question, it was almost 200 when I looked and I was also limited to 20.

Comment: I know, was overwhelming! I saw close to 300 at one point yesterday! That's crazy!!!

Comment: I saw 200+ as well, just as I started closing I noticed that some of them were really old posts, but some were "13 hours ago". I left it, assuming it's a StackExchange bug and they're aware of it. Glad it's resolved now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yesterday, based on [this request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue), we raised the rep requirement to place answers in the Late Answer queue.  Unfortunately, this had some unintended side effects that we weren't planning on and the review queues *exploded* on most sites.

Once the flood of the old answers get reviewed, the worst should be over and answers will trickle in like normal.